# Getting Command "python setup.py egg_info" error when installing packages - Python

Tags: python, pip

Hi I am new to python and I am trying to install it and some of it's packages.
I have installed python on mac with homebrew. I have used this commands 
`# brew install python3`. When I run `# which pip3 python3` to check if is installed I get this

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

So I guess everything is installed.
Now I would like to install some packages. I am doing all installations locally on my computer. 
I would like to install packages in test folder. `annacomp: test anna$ pip install -r ./requirements.txt` but I get this error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pj/dj18qp9s3kjf4w1_pbpjsh2r0000gp/T/pip-build-i4Ksue/psycopg2/
```

[image: Here is screenshot]

I have googled it but I didn't found solution that works for me.

Comment: The error pretty clearly says "`pg_config` executable not found".  Do you have `pg_config` (or any PostgreSQL tools) installed on your computer?

Comment: yes I have installed PostgreSQL @jwodder

Comment: Does that include the `pg_config` program?  Is the program in your PATH?

Comment: I don't know is there any way to check it? @jwodder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that helped me. So these are steps that I took:

1. Install homebrew `# /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install python3 and pip3 `# brew install python3` (to check which version is installed run command `# which pip3 python3`
3. Install virtualenv `# pip3 install virtualenv`
4. Creating virtualenv in which I will install django. Django will
   only be applied for that particular env in my case named `test`. Command `# virtualenv test`
5. Activate virtualenv - you have to be in folder that you created in
   my case `test` and run command `# source bin/activate`
6. Install django `# pip3 install Django`

And after this steps I was able to run command for installing needed packages. Hope it helps.